# Change the git repo url and branch in Azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In the absence of the person who normally does this, I've been asked to change the repo url and branch in the Azure app service in this image.

I can see what the values are currently but I can't find how to change them, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: We use Azure DevOps for CI/CD and we set all those values in the build and release on that end.  They show in the Azure Portal but are read only reporting where it came from.  May be the same case with how you are deploying.

Comment: ah of course, I see it now, thanks!

Comment: posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Azure DevOps for CI/CD and we set all those values in the build and release on that end. They show in the Azure Portal but are read only reporting where it came from. May be the same case with how you are deploying.

Answer (score 0):

Click the (small) "disconnect" link below the word "GitHub".  This seemingly unrelated link will delete the current CD configuration and allow you create a new one.  Leave it Azure to make something that should be trivial about 20% more challenging.